# Hibernate saving User model to Postgres

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, orm

I'm using Postgres via Hibernate (annotations), but it seems to be falling over dealing with a User object:

```
12:09:16,442 ERROR [SchemaExport] Unsuccessful: create table User (id  bigserial not null, password varchar(255), username varchar(255), primary key (id))
12:09:16,442 ERROR [SchemaExport] ERROR: syntax error at or near "User"
```

If I run the SQL manually I have to put quotes around the table name as user seems to be a postgres keyword, but how can I convince hibernate to do this itself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is usually a good practice to avoid names like that

Comment: ....especially if you switch databases regularly, since what is an identifier in the one DB could be a keyword in another. Good style would be pre/suffixes which relate to your application: "myapp_user" as a tablename instead of "user"...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need to escape the table name when using reserved keywords. In JPA 1.0, there is no standardized way and the Hibernate specific solution is to use backticks:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="`User`")
public class User {
    ...
}
```

In JPA 2.0, the standardized syntax looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"User\"")
public class User {
    ...
}
```

#### References

- Hibernate Core documentation

  - [5.4. SQL quoted identifiers](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-quotedidentifiers)
- JPA 2.0 specification

  - 2.13 Naming of Database Objects

Comment: Is there any reason why Hibernate doesn't quote table names by default? I can't think of any situation where this wouldn't be useful.

Comment: @Mr.Omsn: Quoting by default is off because the JPA query language is to be translated into plain SQL. And in SQL identifiers like table names and column names are case __in__-sensitive. So SQL would consider `user` and `User` to be the same table. __BUT__ `"User"` and `"user"` would be different tables which can also exist at the same time. The only difference between PostgreSQL and the SQL standard is: PG folds to lower case but SQL to uppercase.

Answer (score 3):

User is [a key word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html), find a better name or use quotes: "User". (bad idea imho, but it works if you do it *everywhere*)