# How to configure Hibernate to put quotes around table names

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails, grails-orm

I've got a situation where I'm trying to create a table called 'user' in Postgres, which throws an error due to Hibernate not putting table names in quotes:

```
| Error 2012-02-27 23:06:58,782 [Thread-10] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Unsuccessful: create table user (id int8 not null, version int8 not null, account_expired bool not null, account_locked bool not null, email_address varchar(255) not null, enabled bool not null, first_name varchar(255) not null, last_name varchar(255) not null, mobile_number varchar(255) not null, "password" varchar(255) not null, password_expired bool not null, username varchar(255) not null unique, primary key (id))
```

This is despite specifying that it should use the PostgreSQLDialect in DataSource.groovy:

```
dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

How can I configure Hibernate to put quotes around table names when dealing with Postgres?

Comment: I would strongly recommend to use a different table name. Using reserved words will give you problems all over, not only in Hibernate.

Comment: Often enough, renaming the table is not possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can quote the table name in the `mapping` block with backticks. Hibernate will convert those to whatever the quoting approach is for the database based on the Dialect:

```
static mapping = {
    table "`user`"
}
```

You can also just rename the table to something else that doesn't require quoting/escaping, e.g.

```
static mapping = {
    table "users"
}
```

Comment: The person may not be able to rename the table.

Answer (score 4):

This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3611916/947357
It shows how to quote table names in Hibernate and in JPA.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're follwing the same tutorial as I do ("Getting started with Grails" by InfoQ) you've already understood it doesn't provide any coverage to PostgreSQL. Based on [this post](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/New-Grails-Spring-Security-plugin-ONLY-working-with-an-in-memory-database-td2132780.html):

1. "User" is a reserved word in Postgres.
2. The mapping should be added into the class itself (it's not absolutely obvious):

> ```
> class User { 
>    String username 
>    String password 
>    ... 
>    static mapping = { 
>       table 'users' 
>       password column: '`password`' 
>    } 
> }
> ```

or

```
class User { 
   String username 
   String password 
   ... 
   static mapping = { 
      table '`user`' 
      password column: '`password`' 
   } 
}
```