# syntax error on session.save() method

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have got a strange problem, the method session.save() is throwing syntax exception
"org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "user""
-look at the picture attached where you can see mapped table, hibernate query and it's parameters, all looks right, I have no idea where the problem can be.
The column id_user has sequence which is autogenerated, and this value of the sequence is increases every time i try to call the save() method.
The User mapped class:

```
package com.wily.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="user_id_user_seq", name="userSequence")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_user")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="userSequence")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

So, the sequence is increasing, but user is not saved, the image:
[image]

Comment: See also: [Hibernate saving User model to Postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608420/hibernate-saving-user-model-to-postgres/3611916#3611916)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`USER` is a [`PostgreSQL` reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html). Rename the table

```
@Table(name="usertable")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to re-create table in DB and specify some another table name. Please check this link: [How to configure Hibernate to put quotes around table names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463240/how-to-configure-hibernate-to-put-quotes-around-table-names)

Answer (score 0):

if rename didn't work try this
problem is with data base.

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

this will automatically create data base table on any db as per bean class.
also check sequence you created is of same name or not.