# What words are invalid domain class names

Tags: grails

I just installed Grails 3.2.0.M2 and created a new domain class named `Group`.  I then ran the `generate-all *` command and attempted to browsed to the `GroupController`, but was greeted with this error:

```
URI:       /group/index
Class:     org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException
Message:   null
Caused by: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Y0_ FROM GROUP[*] THIS_ "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement: select count(*) as y0_ from group this_ [42001-192]
```

Which is happening here:

```
def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    respond Group.list(params), model:[groupCount: Group.count()] // Error occurs here
}
```

The weird thing is that the problem goes away if I rename the domain class and controller to `Groupz` and `GroupzController` respectively.  Why can't I name my domain class group?  What other names are illegal for domain classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a list of reserved words on the [Grails wiki](https://grails.org/wiki/Reserved%20Names).

Alternatively, you can get around this issue by using the the [static mapping property](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/mapping.html) to rename your class:

```
class Group {
    ...
    static mapping = { table 'my_group' }
    ...
}
```

Comment: You can also continue to use the reserved word but enclose it in backtick characters; this will get Hibernate to use the correct quoting/escaping for that database, as seen in [this older answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9468002/160313).

Answer (score 0):

Well all the domain classes are scanned and converted to the names in following way

User -> user
UserMapping -> user_mapping
and so on.

Basicall the camel case is String is split by the upper case character and then separated by `_`.

> You cannot use any Domain class name that results in the >restricted/reserved words in sql.
>
> e.q group, select, where, from, join, etc

if you still want to use these names in Grails then you can change the table name using `mapping` block. Grails will refer to your domain/entity as the class name but internally bind it to the mapping specified

e.g

```
static mapping {
   table : 'my_table_name'
}
```