# Querying Postgresql using Hibernate (JPA) doesn't find table

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm developing an application using JPA with Hibernate and Postgresql. Using Netbeans wizard, I created entity classes from the existing database. The extract from one of this classes is the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADM_TYPES")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdmTypes.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM AdmTypes a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdmTypes.findByCType", query = "SELECT a FROM AdmTypes a WHERE a.cType = :cType"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdmTypes.findByVlType", query = "SELECT a FROM AdmTypes a WHERE a.vlType = :vlType"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdmTypes.findByDsType", query = "SELECT a FROM AdmTypes a WHERE a.dsType = :dsType"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdmTypes.findByVlStatus", query = "SELECT a FROM AdmTypes a WHERE a.vlStatus = :vlStatus"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdmTypes.findByCTypePrefix", query = "SELECT a FROM AdmTypes a WHERE a.cType like :cTypePrefix")})
public class AdmTypes implements Serializable {
```

In an EJB I have:

```
@Stateless 
@LocalBean
public class ModelManagement {
    @PersistenceContext 
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<AdmTypes> listAdmTypesPrefix(String prefix){
        TypedQuery<AdmTypes> query = em.createNamedQuery("AdmTypes.findByCTypePrefix", AdmTypes.class);
        query.setParameter("cTypePrefix", "'%"+prefix+"%'");
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

When I try to execute `ModelManagement.listAdmTypesPrefix("APREFIX")` It generates the following error:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5193)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5091)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4879)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2039)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1990)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at $Proxy192.listAdmTypesPrefix(Unknown Source)
    at com.librethinking.simmodsys.ejb.__EJB31_Generated__ModelManagement__Intf____Bean__.listAdmTypesPrefix(Unknown Source)
    at com.librethinking.MockServlet.processRequest(MockServlet.java:64)
    at com.librethinking.MockServlet.doGet(MockServlet.java:94)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ERROR: relation "adm_types" does not exist
  Position: 136
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1367)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1295)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:265)
    at com.librethinking.simmodsys.ejb.ModelManagement.listAdmTypesPrefix(ModelManagement.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5366)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5338)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5326)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ERROR: relation "adm_types" does not exist
  Position: 136
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at $Proxy194.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2438)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2424)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2254)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2249)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1248)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:256)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "adm_types" does not exist
  Position: 136
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2101)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1834)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:510)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:386)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:271)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    ... 70 more
```

I know that Postgres is kind of annoying with capitalized table names, but how can I change the query to point to "ADM_TYPES" instead of AdmTypes? Shouldn't this be done automatically (after all I created the entity class from the existing database)? What is wrong with the code?

Thanks!

Comment: If you remove the ' from `"'%"+prefix+"%'"` ? (It doesn't look right).

Comment: No, that's the way it should be done to do a "like" comparison.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Postgres (used to, not sure on the newer) convert table names to lower case. That's the preferred operating procedure. If you log your queries you'll see hibernate may be or may not be quoting your table name (I'd guess it isn't).

[Hibernate saving User model to Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608420/hibernate-saving-user-model-to-postgres/3611916#3611916)

Honestly, if you're running on Postgres you really should either configure hibernate properly, or, as I would look at it, normalize your database as tables shouldn't have a namespace collision (thus removing the problem).

//From the article...

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"User\"")
public class User {
    ...
}
```

**EDITED 07/31/12:**

This change must be done to the fields of the tables in the following way:

For `@Column`, change the name of the column adding escaped ":

```
@Column(name = "\"C_MODEL\"")
```

For `@JoinColumn`, change the name of the column adding `:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "`TP_MODEL`")
```

You will have to do it manually on the columns giving you errors.

Comment: I will try this and let you know!

Comment: Urk, that's horrible. Hibernate should be quoting table names by default. I'd view the failure to do so as a Hibernate bug, personally - and if it's supposed to work this way, it's certainly a NetBeans model generator bug.

Comment: you're right @CraigRinger, it sounds like an error and seems to be already reported

Comment: There are other issues about other things after correcting this error. But this is the answer for this specific problem.

Comment: Hibernate has a lot of little things like this, but I'd hesitate to call this a bug. It allows you to work with less compliant database engines without massive configuration. Its ugly, but it works.

Comment: I edited the answer to add the solution for other problems with fields in this case